# If $(ax+b)(x-3)=4x^2 + cx - 9$ for all values of $x$, what is the value of $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am confused with this problem. Things get confusing because in quadratic form $b$ is actually called $c$ in this problem. Also because I'm not sure where to start. Because it says for all values of $x$, I tried plugging in $1$ for $x$ on both sides.

This gives $(a + b) (-2) = 4 + c - 9$, which simplifies so $-2a-2b = c - 5$. How would I solve from here? There are $3$ variables. Is there a simpler way to solve this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Guess and check isn't really a good way to go. You should simplify $(ax+b)(x-3)$ first then you will start seeing the puzzle pieces coming together.

Comment: Actually plugging in may be easier for the appropriate value (try $x=3$?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved it.

I started by simplifying $(ax + b) (x - 3)=4x^2+cx-9$

This gives $ax^2-3ax+bx-3b=4x^2-cx-9$

By looking at this I can see that $a = 4$ and $b = 3$. If plugged in on the left, this gives

$4x^2-3*4*x+3*x-3*3$ which simplifies to $4x^2-12x+3x-9$ which is $4x^2-9x-9$

Here we can see that $9 = c$.

Comment: As stewbasic  commented, making $x=3$ gives directly the result without searching for $a$ and $b$ since $0=4\times 9+3\times c-9=27-3\times c=0$

Answer (score 0):

In quadratic form, there is no a, b, or c. Here is the quadratic form.
$$(x^2\text{'s coefficient)}x^2 + (x\text{'s coefficient})x + \text{(constant term)}$$

It may be helpful to write out the quadratic formula for the following
$$ax^2 + bx + c$$
$$bx^2 + cx + a$$
$$cx^2 + ax + b$$
$$px^2 + qx + r$$
$$dx^2 + rx + s$$